# if within for within while loop multiple condition and timer python

Tags: python

i want to read (repeatedly) each line of the output command if condition match print line if not keep repeat the loop till timeout and print the current output or a message

it keeps looping in both cases print line or timeup

I want to just print the line once or timeup once if timeout and within the max_time_allowed keep trying the previous command because it may come up after some seconds

```
#Import ConncetHandler feature from netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import time
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import os
#Devices Details

iosv_l2_s1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '1.1.1.1',
    'username': 'sdf',
    'password': 'ss',
}

#SSH to the below devices
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**iosv_l2_s1)
#Apply commands
output = net_connect.send_command('show interface')
max_time_allowed = 15
start = time.time()

while True:
    for line in output.split(os.linesep):
        if re.search(("(?=.*FUlL|2way)(?=.*192.168.0.4)"),line , re.I):
            print line
            start = time.time()
            time.sleep(2)
        elif (time.time() - start) > max_time_allowed:
            print ("timeup")

net_connect.disconnect()
```

Comment: A little coding tip, import all basic modules on one line if you have a lot to clean up your code. e.g: `import time, re, sys etc.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your while loop to stop when time up is reached or your print statement is executed

```
max_time_allowed = 15
start = time.time()
found = 0  

while time.time()-start < max_time_allow and found == 0:
    output = net_connect.send_command('show interface')
    for line in output.split(os.linesep):
        if re.search(("(?=.*FUlL|2way)(?=.*192.168.0.4)"),line , re.I):
            print line
            found = 1
            time.sleep(2)
            break
if found == 0:
    print('TimeOut)
```

Comment: thanks but I have two comments firstly I think you mean
    if found ==0:
second comment it doesn't loop within the timer, I mean if check the first condition to print the line but nothing there so if the status change within the max time allowed still print timeout, I want to continuously check the first condition up to max time allowed if matched print the line or if reached the max time allowed print timeout

Comment: I changed the if statement. I'm not really sure what you mean? This will run you for loop until a timeout happens or your if statement is executed. What do you mean loop within a timer?

Comment: thanks I mean that the loop keep running the same command (show interface) during the max allow timer. the idea is give the device chance (timeout) to bring the interface up if not then I can confirm that interface down as within 15 seconds and interface still down then timeout and confirm it is down. but I think it runs the command once and keep looping within existing output, so even the interface comes up during the running script it doesn't show its status.I need to keep run the command and check its output if true interface up exit loop if not keep trying till get it up or timeout reached

Comment: so what your saying is you need to run the function `net_connet.send_command('show interface')`, until a successful connection is made? If that is the case, what does does that function return? a Boolean True/False or some value??

Comment: Exactly i need to run that command till get condition in if re.search or till reached timeout mentioned in max time allowed

Comment: If condition match in re.search the print this matched line

Comment: so just add it to the while loop, I will put it in the code

Comment: Glad to help, Good Luck